# UIStackView set priority to a child view

Tags: ios, uistackview

Is it possible to set priority to a `child view` of a `UIStackView` like it would be done in android. Set height to 0 and set view`s weight to 1.5 for example?
I want my view to fill little bigger than a half of a screen.

Comment: You can set Aspect Ratio for your view. For example your view's height can be 1/3 of your parenting/neighbouring view height. Or you can set its height to be 1/5 of its width.

Comment: @ZuzanaPaulis, thank you I managed to make it almost working. I think it will be enough for the first time. In next releases I hope I will fix it.

Comment: If it was helpful I will write an answer, I was not sure if it will suit your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set Aspect Ratio constraint for your View for example:

- your view height/width can be 1/3 of your parenting/neighbouring view height/width
- your view height can be 1/5 of its width